# Atualizar variável dentro IF

Tags: php, if, while, else

Bom dia,

Não estou conseguindo atualizar uma variável dentro da estrutura IF e usar ela depois no meu código.

Segue trecho do meu codigo:

```
while ($dado_participante = mysqli_fetch_array($qry2)) { 

    //REGISTRO 0150: TABELA DE CADASTRO DO PARTICIPANTE 

    $cod_part++; //FAZER UM CONTADOR 
    $nome_part = $dado_participante['RAZAO_SOCIAL']; 
    $cod_pais_part = '01058'; 
    $cpf_part = limpa_caracteres_especiais($dado_participante['CPF']); 
    $cnpj_part = limpa_caracteres_especiais($dado_participante['CPF']); 

    if (strlen($cnpj_part == 14)){ 

        $cpf_part = ''; 

    } 

    elseif(strlen($cpf == 11)){ 

        $cnpj_part = ''; 

    } 

    $insc_estadual_part = ''; //Inscrição Estadual do participante. 
    $cod_mun_part = $dado_participante['COD_CIDADE']; 
    $suframa_part = ''; 
    $end_part = $dado_participante['ENDERECO']; 
    $num_part = ''; 
    $compl_part = $dado_participante['COMPLEMENTO']; 
    $bairro_part = $dado_participante['BAIRRO']; 

    //0150 
    $txt .= '|0150|' . $cod_part . '|' . $nome_part . '|' . $cod_pais_part . '|' . $cnpj_part . '|' . $cpf_part . '|' . $insc_estadual_part . '|' . $cod_mun_part . '|' . $suframa_part . '|' . $end_part . '|' . $num_part . '|' . $compl_part . '|' . $bairro_part . '|' . PHP_EOL; 

}
```

Sim, os `cpfs` e `cnjps` estao na mesma coluna no banco de dados, com isso fiz o if para tentar diferencia-los na hora de imprimir no meu código.

Para quando for cnpj imprimir cpf em branco e vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro está aqui:

```
    if (strlen($cnpj_part) == 14){ 

        $cpf_part = ''; 

    } 

    if(strlen($cpf_part) == 11){ 

        $cnpj_part = ''; 

    }
```

No seu código você estava comparando strlen dentro da função, o código a cima deve funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado mas o erro permanece.
As variáveis não estão sendo atualizadas pela estrutura if.

Comment: Se você der um 'echo $cnpj_part.$cpf_part' ele devolve alguma coisa ?

Comment: Obrigado! A sua sugestão realmente funcionou. Na hora de copiar seu trecho de código eu copiei  "$cpf" no lugar de " $cpf_part ".
Muito obrigado pela ajuda!